# LSTM model has a concerning loss graph and returns a constant value on predictions

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, regression, lstm

My dataset is 597515 rows, 31 columns measuring one variable. So input shape (31,1).

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

gpu_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")
for device in gpu_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)

raw_dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv').drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
train_set = raw_dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=42)
test_set = raw_dataset.drop(train_set.index)

import numpy as np

train_features = train_set.copy()
test_features = test_set.copy()

train_labels = train_features.pop('T+1')
test_labels = test_features.pop('T+1')
train_features = train_features.to_numpy().reshape(train_features.shape[0], 31, 1)
test_features = test_features.to_numpy().reshape(test_features.shape[0], 31, 1)
```

Here's my model. Parameters were determined via Optuna, though I found that different configurations result in the same phenomena, just with different values.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(11,return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(13, return_sequences=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0940840143887362),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
                metrics=['mae', 'mse']
                )
history = model.fit(train_features,
                    train_labels,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    batch_size=65536,
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=True
                    )
```

Finally resulting in the following loss graph

[image]

Looking at the predictions I get the following same values

```
array([[-9.407474],
       [-9.407474],
       [-9.407474],
       ...,
       [-9.407474],
       [-9.407474],
       [-9.407474]], dtype=float32)
```

And this is what it looks like plotted against the first 50 test label values.
[image]

I'm pretty much at a loss, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the time dimension in your problem? I feel you are using LSTM wrongly.

Comment: @user2586955 I'm not sure I understand your question? Each value corresponds to a variable at a specific time. I'm trying to identify dependencies between time steps. There are 31 columns thus 31 time steps. It seems LSTM is okay to use here. What am I missing?

Comment: try to scale your series, I think this could be the first step to increase the performances

Comment: @MarcoParola Tried that and obtained a similar loss graph. [The predictions](https://i.imgur.com/sPKA364.png) seem to be a little better though?

Comment: Can you give more insights about your data? what is the row (31 columns) is actually representing? is it a standalone instance or is it correlated with previous and successive rows?

Comment: @user2586955 Each row represents a the value of a technical indicator of a stock, going back thirty days. The first column is the label 'T+1', next column is 'T', next is 'T-1', etc. As a result, successive rows of the same stock will have an overlap of thirty values.

Comment: Interesting, then would you try the LSTM with non overlapping rows, like I think you need the include into training the first row from each 30 rows

Comment: @user2586955 [Definitely some improvement](https://i.imgur.com/I24h36k.png), so I suppose you were correct. Here's the [loss graph](https://i.imgur.com/CwHbhkr.png).

Comment: Nice, then I think now you can proceed by focusing on your architecture like add more LSTM layers and nodes or apply regularisation techniques to see if the validation loss will head down more.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, the problem is caused by two factors:

1. you can improve the preprocessing of your data: (i) perform scaling and (ii) make sure there are no missing-samples.
2. You can improve the architecture of your model, in particular you can increase the number of LSTM units within your LSTM layers. Also, try setting one or two levels; three is probably too many.